# access Json as result of ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, resultset

Hi how can i handle this json response from ajax

```
{"suivi":5,
"mail":8,
"listSuivi":{
      "0":{"dossier":"IWE123123","refunds_count":1},
      "1":{"dossier":"IM00000009","refunds_count":2}
   }
 }
```

i can access to suivi and mail doing this

```
    success: function(data){

      $('#suivi').html(data.mail+" +");
      $('#mail').html(data.suivi+" +");
    }
```

but how  can i obtain the list of dossiers (listSuivi)?
Thx a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Note that despite its name `listSuivi` is not a list, it is a map with the keys being string representations of integers.

Comment: ah ok so i need also to change the name to be more precise?

Comment: `Object.values(data.listSuivi).map(s => s.dossier)` ?

Comment: i can access to the first element doing this data["listSuivi"][0]["dossier"] but how can loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the items with a for loop.

Some options are a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```js
const data = {
  "suivi":5,
  "mail":8,
  "listSuivi":{
    "0":{"dossier":"IWE123123","refunds_count":1},
    "1":{"dossier":"IM00000009","refunds_count":2}
  }
};

// For ... in loop
for(const key in data.listSuivi) {
  const item = data.listSuivi[key];
  
  console.log("Object: ", item);
  console.log("Dossier:", item.dossier);
  console.log("Refunds:", item.refunds_count);
}
```

Or a [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop in combination with [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const data = {
  "suivi":5,
  "mail":8,
  "listSuivi":{
    "0":{"dossier":"IWE123123","refunds_count":1},
    "1":{"dossier":"IM00000009","refunds_count":2}
  }
};

// For ... of loop with Object.values
for(const item of Object.values(data.listSuivi)) {
  console.log("Object: ", item);
  console.log("Dossier:", item.dossier);
  console.log("Refunds:", item.refunds_count);
}
```